# Can not call my recursion function in javascript/Polymer

Tags: javascript, recursion, polymer

I have a function that searches through a tree of folders and finds the selected folder's parent folder.

Here is the function.

```
        getParentFolder: function (searchroot, childFolder) {
            searchroot.subfolders.forEach(function (folder) {
                if (folder.key == childFolder.key) {
                    return searchroot;
                }
                else {
                    if (folder.subfolders) {
                        return this.getParentFolder(folder, childFolder);
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

When I call this with `this.getParentFolder(rootFolder, childFolder);`

It simply just gives me: Uncaught TypeError: this.getParentFolder is not a function
Why is this? In the same file I call other functions they work perfectly fine. This is the only function that I fail to be able to call. Is it because of the recursion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to keep `this` in a variable as you change your context inside the `forEach` method.

```
getParentFolder: function(searchroot, childFolder) {
  var self = this;
  searchroot.subfolders.forEach(function(folder) {
    if (folder.key == childFolder.key) {
      return searchroot;
    } else {
      if (folder.subfolders) {
        return self.getParentFolder(folder, childFolder);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Also, `return` statement won't work the way you want. I recommend you to enumerate the array using a for loop :

```
getParentFolder: function(searchroot, childFolder) {
  for (var i = 0; i < searchroot.subfolders.length; i++) {
    var folder = searchroot.subfolders[i];
    if (folder.key == childFolder.key) {
      return searchroot;
    } else {
      if (folder.subfolders) {
        return self.getParentFolder(folder, childFolder);
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: so does this mean each time I call this in any loop because the nature of javascript, I have to reasign this to self every single time?

Comment: Absolutely, if you want to keep track of you main object. Alternatively, you can use [`bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind)

Comment: @nanobots, you can pass the outer `this` as an argument to the `forEach` which avoids having to use `self`.

Comment: @SumnerEvans forgot this one :)

Comment: I see I see because the temp function created by the foreach(function()) changes the context of this that is why I am having this problem is that correct?

Comment: @nanobots, exactly.

Comment: @NathanP., +1 for note on return statement not being correct.

Comment: I see if I use for loop instead of foreach this would be avoided as this never changes. However when I apply the recursion without the foreach and with just simple for loop, do I still have to do return self.getParentFolder, or this.getParentFolder? I mean this doesn't change , but would the this changes inside the call of recursion?

Comment: If you use the for loop solution, you can avoid using self since you stay inside your object.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that your `this` is different inside of function you passed into the `forEach`. You need to bind the outer `this` to the inner function:

```
getParentFolder: function(searchroot, childFolder) {
  searchroot.subfolders.forEach(function(folder) {
    if (folder.key == childFolder.key) {
      return searchroot;
    } else {
      if (folder.subfolders) {
        return this.getParentFolder(folder, childFolder);
      }
   }
  }, this); // pass in outer this as context for inner function
}
```

---

**From [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) on MDN:**

> **Syntax:**
>
> ```
> arr.forEach(function callback(currentValue, index, array) {
>    //your iterator
> }[, thisArg]);
> ```

---

**Alternative Solution using ES6:**

As [mishu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/521598/mishu) mentioned in the comments, the new ES6 arrow syntax also solves this problem. Your code in ES6 would look something like this:

```
getParentFolder: function(searchroot, childFolder) {
  searchroot.subfolders.forEach((folder) => {
    if (folder.key == childFolder.key) {
      return searchroot;
    } else {
      if (folder.subfolders) {
        return this.getParentFolder(folder, childFolder);
      }
    }
  });
}
```

Arrow functions is ES6 do not bind `this` (see [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this)) so the outer `this` can be accessed from within the arrow function.

Note that not all browsers support arrow functions yet (see [Browser compatibility on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#Browser_compatibility)). To support older browsers, you can transpile ES6 to ES5 using [Babel](https://babeljs.io/).

Comment: wouldn't the new ES6 arrow syntax also solve this issue, as there's no binding on `this`? https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions#No_binding_of_this

Comment: @mishu, yes, updated my answer to include that. Good suggestion!